# A little help to understand events (noob question)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I'm learning as3 and I'm having difficulties understanding events.

I'm trying to load options inside an array that I will later need to access to load images.

Now..

```
private function init(e:Event = null):void {

    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

    myLoader.load(new URLRequest("slides.xml"));
    myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXMLSlides);
    ...
}

private function processXMLSlides(e:Event):void {

    removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXMLSlides);

    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    myXML.ignoreWhite=true;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < myXML.IMAGE.length(); i++) {
        imagesURLs.push(myXML.IMAGE[i]);
        //trace(myXML.IMAGE[i]);
    }
    //Start the main routine.
    loadImages();
    writeImage(imageCurrent);
}
```

loadImages() takes the array imagesURLs and loads them inside another array as URLRequests and then writeImage() writes the image to the stage.

Now the thing is this. If I move the loadImages() and writeImage() function here:

```
   private function init(e:Event = null):void {

        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        myLoader.load(new URLRequest("slides.xml"));
        myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXMLSlides);

            //Start the main routine.
        loadImages();
        writeImage(imageCurrent);
        ...
    }
```

It doesn't work because loadImages gets called BEFORE the array gets populated from the xml. Now how can I tell as3 to wait for the processXMLSlides to finish its thing?
Do I need another event? Is this stupid (there are better ways to do what I'm doing)?

Thanks

Comment: just a note:  event listeners need to be removed from their dispatchers.  for example  myLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXMLSlides);, evt.target.removeEventListener... or evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener ...

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 why do you say that? You need to remove the eventListeners only if there is a reason, not every time.

Comment: sorry, i wasn't clear.  i've stated that the code above is incorrect since myLoader is adding the event listener and dispatching the event, but the parent of myLoader is trying to remove the event listener, which it doesn't own.  also, event listeners should be removed if they are not being used, otherwise you'll run into trouble regarding garbage collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't make sense, your first example is doing exactly what you are asking for - waiting for the XML to be loaded.

Flash Events are very handy in handling asynchronous processes - like XML loading - how long would you wait otherwise before calling the `loadImages();` and `writeImage(imageCurrent);`? The answer is exactly as long as it takes for the XML to load. So keep it where it is, in the event handler method.

*NOTE:*

Add the listener to myLoader first and call the load() method only afterwards. When testing on a local environment (from a hard drive) it can happen that the "slides.xml" will load immediately and the COMPLETE event will be fired before the eventListener is attached.

Comment: Thanks now I understand better the whole issue.

Answer (score 1):

this is untested code, but something like this should work:

```
private function init(e:Event = null):void
    {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

    myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXMLSlides);
    myLoader.load(new URLRequest("slides.xml"));
    }

private function processXMLSlides(e:Event):void
    {
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXMLSlides);

    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    myXML.ignoreWhite = true;

    for each    (var element:XML in myXML..IMAGE)
                {
                var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
                imageLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, writeImage);
                imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(element));
                }
    }

private function writeImage(e:Event):void
    {
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, writeImage);
    addChild(evt.currentTarget);
    }
```

you might want to stick with the var i:uint for loop, though, as you could use it to position the placement of each of your images.

have a read of the [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) class.  there are many examples provided for class specific eventss you could use for your specific needs.